# apache won't start when configuring php

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I am trying to configure php 5.3.6 with apache 2.2.17. apache runs fine, but will not start once i added entries to httpd.conf for php. the error log has stopped putting entries in when i try to start apache as well.

here are the entries i added, in the appropriate places in http.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP"
```

i have been researching this, but have not been able to find what i am doing wrong. i added double quotes to the paths as there are spaces in them, which resolved a loadmodule error in the log, only now i have no info to go as to what i am missing. any help would be appreciated. i would prefer not to use the all in one installers like wamp server, etc. thanks!